# assigning value for edit template controls on rowdatabound

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have one user control whose values i want to assign on rowdatabound:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delivery Date">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblDeliveryDate" CssClass="NormalText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DDateTime") %>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
   <uc1:WUCDateHourMin ID="WUCDeliverydate" runat="server" />
   </EditItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

I am binding values for edittemplate on rowdatabound as:

```
If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
  CType(e.Row.FindControl("WUCDeliverydate"), WUCDateHourMin).BindFromDateTime(gc.GetDate(e.Row.DataItem("EDateTime")), 0, 0)
End If
```

But Its binding only alternate rows (Odd number rows, 1st, 3rd, 5th) . I dont know what is happening.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**I done it like follows:**

```
 If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then
                If IsDBNull(e.Row.DataItem("DDateTime")) Then
                    CType(e.Row.FindControl("WUCDeliverydate"), WUCDateHourMin).BindFromDateTime(gc.GetDate(Now()), 0, 0)
                Else
                    CType(e.Row.FindControl("WUCDeliverydate"), WUCDateHourMin).BindFromDateTime(gc.GetDate(e.Row.DataItem("EDateTime")), 0, 0)
                End If

            End If
```